# My first exceptions code. Can someone try this out and let me know how to make this more efficient?

Tags: performance

{
internal class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{   //Main program using 2 functions to convert fahrenheit to celsius
//as long as the user would like to do so
tempConvert();
goOrNo();
}
public static void tempConvert()
{//function for converting temperature degree from celsius to fehrenheit or vice versa

```
        try 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a program to convert fahrenheit to celsius, or vice      versa.");
          Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter C to convert to celsius or F to convert to fahrenheit.");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();

            if (choice == "C" || choice == "c")
            {
             Console.WriteLine();
               Console.WriteLine("Now enter the amount of temperature you wish to convert to C.");

                double degreesF = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                 double f2C = (degreesF - 32) \* (5.0 / 9.0);
             Console.WriteLine();
               Console.WriteLine("{0} degrees fahrenheit is: {1} degrees celsius", degreesF, f2C);
            }
            else if (choice == "F" || choice == "f")
            {
             Console.WriteLine();
               Console.WriteLine("Now enter the amount of temperature you wish to convert to F.");
                double degreesC = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                double c2F = ((1.8 \* degreesC) + 32);
             Console.WriteLine();
               Console.WriteLine("{0} degrees celsius is: {1} in fahrenheit.", degreesC, c2F);
            }
            
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
         Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("This is unacceptable.");
         Console.WriteLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
                     goOrNo();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
     public static void goOrNo()
    {//function to start program again or exit
        try
        {
          Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to convert temperatures from fahrenheit to celsius? Enter Y to continue or anything else to exit.");
            string noGo = Console.ReadLine();
            while (noGo == "Y" || noGo == "y")
            {
             Console.WriteLine();
                     tempConvert();
            }
          Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 'Y' or 'y' next time to continue converting temperatures.");

          Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        catch (FormatException) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input"); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.Write(ex.Message); }
     }
 }
```

}

I am trying to make it where the user can not break the code, and if they do it throws an exception and takes them right back to the code. It seems I have succeeded, but I could very well be wrong.